# Multilple PersistenceContext CDI

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I want to parameter two connections to DataBase.

I create two producers :

```
@Singleton
public class DataBaseProducerDB2 {

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "contratbusiness")
    private EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEm() {return em;}

}
```

---

```
@Singleton
public class DataBaseProducerMySQL {

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AutreSQL")
    private EntityManager em;

}
```

---

Then, I inject the producer i need for my test,

```
@Stateless(name = "contratbusiness.net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.queries.DacomccbQueries")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
@LocalBean
@Default
public class DacomccbQueries {

    @Inject
    private DataBaseProducerMySQL baseProducerMySQL;

    public List<Object[]> findInfosContratOuvert(final String contrat) {
        final TypedQuery<Object[]> query = this.baseProducerMySQL.getEm().createNamedQuery(
                "net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacomccb.findInfosContratOuvert", Object[].class);
        query.setParameter("contrat", contrat);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

I don't understand why when i m launching the Junit Test with the SQL producer , the DB2 producer is launched instead.

```
@RunWith(EJBContainerRunner.class)
public class DacomccbQueriesTest {
    @Inject
    private  DacomccbQueries dacomccbQueries;
}
```

Here the log :

> (SchemaExport.java:perform:426)  -[DataDirect][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]...

**UPDATE**: adding persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="contratbusiness" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/contratbusiness.DB</jta-data-source>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacomccb</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbcpt</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacpt</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbadr</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbdvs</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacompdv</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.keyid.DaccbcptId</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.keyid.DacomccbId</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
           <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="AutreSQL" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/contratbusiness.DB</jta-data-source>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacomccb</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbcpt</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacpt</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbadr</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Daccbdvs</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.Dacompdv</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.keyid.DaccbcptId</class>
        <class>net.awl.bfi.contratbusiness.entities.keyid.DacomccbId</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.mysql.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `persistence.xml` which contains `AutreSQL` persistence unit? If both are in same `persistence.xml`, post entire `persistence.xml`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, below the persistance.xml.

Comment: you can delete the answer, I edited your question with `persistence.xml`. It looks OK. When you run your test, only DB2 is launched? 'Cause both will be produced...

Comment: Yes, only DB2 is launched, but it should not, because i inject the DataBaseProducerMySQL to launch only MySQL.

Comment: Well, in your `persistence.xml` both persistence units uses the same `data-source`. See if one of them is not wrong configured.

Comment: Yes , it was a mistake , i changed the value of data-source and it works. Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Both persistence units uses the same data-source, so when the data-source has been modified it works.